# crossdomain messaging in mobile App

Tags: openfire

I have two App, one is for internal employee, another is for customer. I have two message servers (which uses openfire) for the two App. How do I configure the two openfire to talk to each other?

Comment: Please explain your need and look for it before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Openfire has "server to server" feature which can support this requirement. I have configured this feature and let two clients to connect to two openfire servers, and openfire server 1 will talk to openfire server 2.